# Стандартный стиль CheckBox поверх моего

Tags: android

Доброго времени суток. 
Пишу кастомный CheckBox, но почему-то виден стандартный вид CheckBox, поверх моего

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

```
    <selector  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_cb_off" />
        <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_cb_on" />
    </selector>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поскольку вы не дали достаточно кода, могу лишь предположить, что вышеприведённый `drawable selector` вы устанавливаете как `android:background`, вместо `android:button`.

Comment: именно это я и сделал, спасибо